# Search in a range of cells for specific stage

Tags: excel

[image: Excel Data]

So I am trying to search within Column C, if any text within column A exists there.
For example, in A8, there's strawberry and orange. Under column C, orange exists, but it's showing as not found. Here's my formula:

```
= IF(A8<>"", IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("*"&A8&"*",$C$2:$C$7,1,FALSE)), "Not Found", VLOOKUP("*"&A8&"*",$C$2:$C$7,1,FALSE)), "Not Found")
```

The wildcard search doesn't seem to be working. What's a better way to do this? I need column F to return the text that was found in Column C.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(C1,A1)>0,FALSE),C1,"Not Found")

Comment: This doesn't work. I should have clarify that I'm trying to search through the range of column C which is C2 - C7 instead of just C2.